# Prevent from duplicates on async insert on postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, function, triggers, auto-increment

I have a trigger that basically get the last number inserted (folio) based on two columns (service_type and prefix) and then increment one value. Everything works fine but in some situations when there a lot of insert statements at the same time it causes that the function use the same last value inserted and it duplicates the folio column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_folio()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE incremental INTEGER;
SELECT max(f.folio) INTO incremental FROM "folios" f
WHERE f.prefix = NEW."prefix" AND service_type = NEW."service_type";
NEW."folio" = incremental + 1;
IF NEW."folio" IS NULL THEN NEW."folio" = 1;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$

CREATE TRIGGER insert_folio BEFORE INSERT ON "folios" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_folio();
```

sample:

| folio | service_type | prefix |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DOCUMENT | DC |
| 1 | IMAGE | IMG |
| 1 | IMAGE | O |
| 2 | IMAGE | O |
| 2 (This should be 3) | IMAGE | O |

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have concurrent transactions that both see the same data. The second transaction does not see the record inserted by the first transaction until the first commits.

To prevent this behaviour you will have to [lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-lock.html) the whole table when inserting to prevent concurrent writes or use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) to prevent concurrent insertions of the same `service_type` and `prefix`.